# SQL Lite syntax for finding a specific pattern

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I am trying to create an SQL LIKE syntax that matches something like:

```
String 1:
    [
        {"event_uuid":"9419b4d0-69d5-0137-34e0-218193219df4",
        "status":"checked_in",
        "updated_at":"2019-09-16T08:16:10.189+02:00"
        }, 
        {"event_uuid":"218193219df4-9419b4d0-69d5-0137-34e0",
        "status":"checked_out",
        "updated_at":"2019-09-16T08:16:10.189+02:00"
        }
    ]


String 2:
    [
        {"event_uuid":"9419b4d0-69d5-0137-34e0-218193219df4",
        "status":"checked_out",
        "updated_at":"2019-09-16T08:16:10.189+02:00"
        }, 
        {"event_uuid":"218193219df4-9419b4d0-69d5-0137-34e0",
        "status":"checked_in",
        "updated_at":"2019-09-16T08:16:10.189+02:00"
        }
    ]
```

I tried the following, without success:

```
LIKE '%9419b4d0-69d5-0137-34e0-218193219df4%[^}]%checked_in%'
```

The json array is saved as a string in the database, I need a LIKE syntax that matches the first string but not the second one, for example:

```
LIKE '%9419b4d0-69d5-0137-34e0-218193219df4%checked_in%'
```

- would match both of them

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Should we assume you have 3 seperate columns in the table called `event_uuid` and `status` and `updated_at` ??

Comment: Please show us ALL the query that you have written, just a snippet is not really helping us to help you

Comment: RiggsFolly -  didn't use "code" as it does not work with bold - wanted to highlight some fields.

Comment: Dan feel free to amend my edit, I just tried to make what you placed in the question a little more readable

Comment: backend is a bit off a mess.. this is actually content off one column

Comment: Can you show us the data you are trying to match on the database

Comment: The json array is saved as a string in the database, I need a LIKE syntax that matches the first string but not the second one, for example: LIKE '%9419b4d0-69d5-0137-34e0-218193219df4%checked_in%' - would match both of them

Comment: do you need any other info ?

Comment: What are the rules for determining if an object in the array matches or not?

Comment: Hint: Don't treat it like a string, treat it like a JSON array: https://sqlite.org/json1.html

Comment: parsing the content and creating a json array is expensive and creates a lot o overhead on a large dataset (I'm using it with COUNT), so SQL LIKE is the fastest approach

Comment: Thanks for the hint Shawn, unfortunately I'm doing this in android and can't use extensions.